My question is for Unitarians? When Jesus was on earth in bodily form He could only be in one place at a time. Reconcile this with Matthew 18:20
Matthew 18:20, "For where two or three are gathered together in My name, there I am in their midst." The same idea is also expressed at John 14:23, "Jesus answered and said to him, "If anyone loves Me, he will keep My word; and My Father will love him, and WE will come to him, and make Our "abode" with him."
That Jesus is present wherever people are gathered in His name speaks of His deity. So, how can this be in view of the fact that only God is omnipresent?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Not calling myself a Unitarian, but I think as a Jehovah's Witness I share the same belief as many other Unitarians in terms of Jesus not being God Almighty, and the Holy Spirit not being a person but God's power or "the finger of God" (compare Matthew 12:28 with Luke 11:20).
On a basic level, the question is easily answered:
If Jesus were God Almighty and if He were omnipresent, Jesus' statement in Matthew 18:20 would be misleading, for He basically says that if "two or three are gathered together in My name, there I am in their midst." - but what if one is alone? And if they are 2 or more, what if they are not gathered together in Jesus' name? Is Jesus then still in their midst? Jesus' own words would imply that the answer is NO.
So Matthew 18:20 has nothing to do with Jesus being "omnipresent".
What was Matthew 18:20 actually about? The context clearly speaks about Christian gatherings, whether it be made up of fewer than ten or of several thousand worshipers of God, for Jesus said: “Where there are two or three gathered together in my name, there I am in their midst”! The context shows that primarily, when making that promise, Jesus was discussing judicial matters that needed to be handled correctly by those taking the lead in the congregation. (Matthew 18:15-19) However, Jesus’ words can also be applied in principle to all Christian gatherings that are opened and closed with prayer in his name! Remember, when Jesus commissioned his followers to do the disciple-making work, he promised: “And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.”—Matthew 28:20.
There can be no doubt that the Head of the Christian congregation, the Lord Jesus Christ, is keenly interested in all gatherings of his faithful followers. Moreover, we can be sure that he is present with them by means of God’s holy spirit. Jesus "has received from the Father the promised Holy Spirit and has poured out what you now see and hear." (Acts 2:33)
Jesus is the "The Lamb [that] had seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven spirits of God sent out into all the earth." (Revelation 5:6)
Jesus is thus "in the midst" of those who are gathered together in his name, through God's holy spirit (God's power). This does not require any omnipresence by Jesus, as He is with his followers in spirit, just as Paul was with the Corinthians when He said: "So when you are assembled and I [Paul] am with you in spirit, and the power of our Lord Jesus is present, hand this man over to Satan for the destruction of the flesh, so that his spirit may be saved on the day of the Lord." (1. Corinthians 5:4,5). Paul is not omnipresent, is He?

You said, "So when you are assembled and I [Paul] am with you in spirit," The omnipresence of Jesus Christ is not like people at a football game cheering on their favorite team as in were with you. John 14:23, "If anyone loves Me he will keep My word, and My Father will love him, and WE WILL COME TO HIM AND MAKE OUR ABODE WITH HIM." That is, live in a person. 1 Corinthains 3:16, "Do you not know that you are a temple of God, and that the Spirit of God DWELLS IN YOU." Galatians 2:20 says that "Christ lives in me." Btw, you said "God's holy spirit, why not use God's active force?

@Mr.Bond - So what does "live in a person", or "dwell in you" mean to you? I think it's an intimate friendship with God an His Son, going as far as positively influencing our personality and impacting our decisions. It is God's active force - His holy spirit affecting and supporting us. They are with us in spirit, and not physically in us. John 15:15; 16:27; 17:22; Hebrews 3:1; 1 John 3:2, 24. "Close friendship with Jehovah belongs to those who fear him, And he makes his covenant known to them." (Psalm 25:14) - It means that they are constantly alive in our thoughts.

It means that God indwells or lives in a person through His Spirit. 1 Corinthians 3:16, "Do you not know that you are a temple of God, and the Spirit of God dwells in you?" You were taught and believe that the Holy Spirit of God is impersonal, an active force, not a person. See here: https://www.gotquestions.org/Holy-Spirit-person.html This is why I brought up John 14:23, "We will make OUR abode with him." Acts 5:3-4, "Ananias lied to the Holy Spirit, You have not lied to men, but to God." One cannot lie to an active force or compare the HS to electricity impacting our decisions.

@Mr.Bond - The gotquestions.org omits quite a lot of Bible verses in connection with the holy spirit. For a more complete exposition (which includes ALL verses from the gotquestions.org article) you can read it here: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200004211 - No, the holy spirit is not a distinct person of the Godhead. God's dwelling describes a state of being in union with him. As servants of God, "[God] is our dwelling place", and we live in the shadow of the Almighty (Psalm 90:1; 91:1) - we are "guests in His tent". (Psalm 15:1,2)

When God's spirit dwells in us, it means that we are dwelling with God. It's figurative speech, describing our state of accepting God in our hearts, subjecting ourselves to God.  It means that we fully accepted that we "no longer belong to ourselves" (1 Corinthians 6:19; Romans 14:8). It means that we strive to live according to the spirit and not to the flesh (Romans 7:21-25). In fact we ENSLAVE ourselves to God and Christ (1 Corinthians 7:22, 23) - so when God "dwells in us" we are His slave, subjecting to the power of God's spirit (his influential force). - Compare Revelation 19:1, 2, 5

Hold on a minute Js. I first gave you John 14:23 about God the Father and His Son making their abode in a person. Explain how "a God/a creature" indwell a person? Not only that but this "a God/creature said, "When the Helper/Holy Spirit comes, whom I WILL SEND to you from the Father." John 15:26. John 15:4, "Abode in Me and I IN YOU." So Js, is Jesus Christ an active force like electricity or a person? In short, all three persons of the Trinity indwell people when they are born again. Btw, what does born again mean to you? Are you born again? If you answer yes how did you become born again?

@Mr.Bond - if a demon can indwell a person, why shouldn't Jesus be able to do so? When Jesus said "I will send the helper from the Father", then where does the Helper come from? From the Father! In John 14:26 Jesus talked about  "the Comforter, which is the Holy Ghost, whom the Father will send in my name". How so? Because Jesus asked the Father permission to use his active force for the purpose of guiding His followers when He would no longer be physically present with them - John 14:16. Through the holy spirit Jesus would still guide and help them.

That the Father, Jesus and the spirit of God indwell a person is explained by Jesus' own words in John 14:20: "you will realize that I am in my Father, and you are in me, and I am in you." How can Jesus indwell the Father? How can we indwell Jesus while Jesus indwells us, and at the same time indwells the Father? I give you a hint - it has nothing to do with omnipresence as your OP question suggests. It has everything to do with intimate relationship - being present with a person in a spiritual sense, without physical proximity involved.

I am not disputing that the Father, Son and Holy Spirit indwells a believer in a spiritual sense. John 4:24, "those who worship Him must worship Him in SPIRIT AND TRUTH. The term "abode" is used at John 14:2 where it is rendered "mansions." Those who love Jesus and treasure His Word become temples for His presence. 1 Corinthians3:16 backs this up. So does Revelation 3:20, "Behold, I stand at the door and knock; if anyone hears My voice and opens the door, I will come in to him, and will dine with him, and be with him." How is this not omnipresence? It says, "If anyone opens his heart I enter."
